# Они не гарантируют точного результата или точный результат"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Какой падеж нужен? Или, может быть, вообще лучше перестроить эту фразу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В текстах для  ***не гарантировать*** встречаются оба варианта (Р. п. и В. п), но Р. п. чаще. Розенталь также рекомендует Р. п. при отрицании **для отвлеченных существительных:**

[**§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Родительный падеж, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции **значение подчеркнутого отрицания,** обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:

при выражении дополнения **отвлеченными существительными**:
не дает оснований, не обнаруживает понимания, не теряет надежды, не скрывает радости, не осуществляет контроля, не упускает случая, не делает уступок.
Например: Здесь шума не любят (Горький); Веселья я не ищу (В. Кетлинская); Утро не принесло ясности (Леонов).

Пример:

Вот она ― вторая составляющая загадочной русской футбольной души: никакие деньги **не гарантируют** в нашем футболе **стабильного результата.**

Answer (score 2):

Словари на Грамоте говорят, что именительный. Но у нас есть отрицание, которое позволяет использовать как именительный, так и родительный/винительный.

А перестраивать ничего не нужно - всяк красиво.

**[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)**

**ГАРАНТИРОВАТЬ**, -рую, -руешь; гарантированный; -ван, -а, -о; св. и нсв. [франц. garantir] **что**. 1. Дать - давать гарантию в чём-л.; обеспечить - обеспечивать. Г. высокое качество продукции. Г. своевременное возвращение ссуды, долга. Г. сохранение должности на время декретного отпуска. Г. чью-л. безопасность. 2. **от чего**. Оградить - ограждать, защитить - защищать. Никто не гарантирован от ошибок. Г. от всяких неожиданностей.

**Управление в русском языке**

**ГАРАНТИРОВАТЬ** — 1. [обеспечить] **кому что**. Гарантировать больным хороший уход. 2. [защитить] **кого от чего**. Гарантировать путешественников от несчастных случаев.

См. также

**[Варианты падежных форм дополнения при переходных глаголах без отрицания и с отрицанием](https://psyera.ru/varianty-padezhnyh-form-dopolneniya-pri-perehodnyh-glagolah-bez-otricaniya-i-s-otricaniem_8730.htm)**